# iPython notebook : disable execution

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm running 2 notebook server. The first is private, and need an authentication in order to edit the notebooks. The other one is public, and I would like to put it as a "Show room".

In fact, the public one is likely an equivalent of Apache's "index of", showing the differents notebooks I made. I would like to know if there's a way to disable the execution of cells in all the notebooks on the public server.

Comment: I'd suggest you create HTML export of notebooks and host them in a static file folder.

Comment: or maybe have a look at http://nbviewer.ipython.org/ (you can also run one yourself: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/faq#can-i-run-my-own-notebook-viewer )

Comment: Your two ideas work well, and i'm curently using this way. I hope I'll find a solution on this issue, because it would be really easyier for me.